# Web scraping element missing in html

Tags: r, web-scraping, tidyverse, rvest, httr

I have this simple scraping code in R

```
library(rvest)

url_blue <- "https://www.cronista.com/MercadosOnline/moneda.html?id=ARSB"

blue <- read_html(url_blue) %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath="//div[@class='col-venta']//span") %>% 
  html_text()
```

The result is : "VENTA:" ""

The first element is OK. The second element is the problem.

In the webpage the element is this and has a value:

[image]

It's very strange and i can't find a solution on internet.Is there something that I did not understand?

Thank you so much! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[Check this XHR log here you can find the URL of that data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ1p3.png)

```
url_blue <- "https://www.cronista.com/MercadosOnline/json/getValoresCalculadora.html"


blue <- read_html(url_blue) %>% html_text()
```

Now, I think you can derive fruitful things out of this. Happy Holidays!!

Comment: That link is a JSON file, you need `jsonlite` to convert to R object not `rvest::read_html()`: `df <- jsonlite::fromJSON("https://www.cronista.com/MercadosOnline/json/getValoresCalculadora.html")`

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be to use `Rselenium` library.

Below a possible solution:

```
library(RSelenium)
driver <- rsDriver(browser=c("firefox"), port = 4449L)
remote_driver <- driver[["client"]]
remote_driver$navigate('https://www.cronista.com/MercadosOnline/moneda.html?id=ARSB')
compra<-remote_driver$findElement(using = 'css selector', value = ".col-compra")$getElementText()
print(compra)
[1] "COMPRA:\n154,00"
venta<-remote_driver$findElement(using = 'css selector', value = ".col-venta")$getElementText()
print(venta)
[1] "VENTA:\n159,00"
```